# Update Micronaut metric without a controller or a job

Tags: kotlin, micronaut, micrometer, micronaut-micrometer

I'm working in a micronaut project, using Kotlin, and I want to use micrometer to create a metric related with the number of entries that I've in the database.

My question is: The update of this metric must rely on a cronjob? What I want is when the metric's endpoint is requested (eg `/metrics/name`) it authomaticaly updates the metric and return the response. However, I don't want to have a route in a controller dedicated to it. So there's any way of doing it?
Regards

Comment: If you can summarize why it is that you want it to be a metric and why you don't want a controller involved, that might help identify the best solution for your needs.

Comment: Hi @JeffScottBrown. So basically I want to monitor with a gauge, probably, how much entries respect some condition. It's important for me since if this value increases a lot we will have problems in our system. I think that I don't need a controller for that because I want to implement it as jvm.memory or any other built-in meter of micrometer. Do you have any idea how can I do it? Regards

Comment: "So basically I want to monitor with a gauge" - Are you going to have a system polling the metric endpoint to retrieve the data?

Comment: Yes I will @JeffScottBrown